Postfix relay mails from alias domain to main server
I use my own server as a relay for customers sending newsletters. It's necessary because of the webhoster limitations.
I've added the domains as virtual_alias_domains and a webmaster@ to virtual_alias_maps file for bounces. DKIM and SPF is also configured and running perfectly. Except for addresses from the same domain inside the mail distribution list.
If user1@virtual_example.org tries to email user2@virtual_example.org using my mail server, postfix is looking for user2 in the virtual aliases and send it to webmaster@virtual_example.org.

The error message is: User unknown in relay recipient table

I could now add all existing addresses from @virtual_example.org to the alias map file, but there are many. Instead, I am looking for a solution to forward all mails from the alias domain to the main mail server.
I tried to use a transport_maps file, but I am not sure, it works the way I am using it.

I guess I found a solution. But I am unsure it's a proper way.
Again: I wanted to use the server as a relay host for an external domain. For Newsletters and so on. Instead of keeping mails with recipients of this domain, I want to send them back to the main server, where the mail accounts are organized.
Instead of virtual_alias_domain I assigned the domain as virtual_mailbox_domain in main.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = example.org

Then I added a transport rule to the transport file.
example.org smtp:mail.example_hoster.net

Can someone please confirm, that this is the right way, and it has no issues?

TL;DR use relay_domains and fill the list of addresses that exist in the domain into relay_address_maps instead of meddling with virtual_* things.


I could now add all existing addresses from @virtual_example.org to the alias map file, but there are many. Instead, I am looking for a solution to forward all mails from the alias domain to the main mail server.

In the Postfix docs you may find multiple statements of the following maxima: reject early. Rejecting mail for unknown recipients is one of the basic anti-spam features that Postfix offers out of the box, in the form of built-in permission checks that do exactly that and produce dedicated reject reasons ("User unknown in local/virtual/relay recipient table"). Most of the time it's better to reject than to accept and face the consequences — increased spam and so on; one of concrete reasons is that after-queue filtering (typical way Amavis is hooked in, via alternate transport and with re-injecting mail back into Postfix) is susceptible to backscatter problem where you may become a spammer involuntarily, which is why I have a strong dislike of this kind of hookup in favor of before-queue filtering (which is how permissions lists and most milters work), that rejects right away, during SMTP session, and never generates any non-delivery notifications that may become a backscatter.
Here I am trying to convince you that it is best to give the front-end server (or relay, whatever that handles interactions with third party) the most knowledge of what addresses are actually exist (are deliverable) on the target server (your client's). Yes, it means, you need to fill a large table on the front-end, and even implement an automation which updates that table whenever the list of addresses changes on the target side.


Instead of virtual_alias_domain I assigned the domain as virtual_mailbox_domain in main.cf

The main document for this topic is Postfix's ADDRESS CLASS README. Please, read it carefully, and ask questions, if something's not clear. What you did is you've broke the logic that is already implemented in the Postfix and re-implemented it using a facility designated for different purpose. This is not "the right way", of course.
The virtual_mailbox_domains variable specifies hosted domains that have addresses for which this mail system is a final destination, but users don't have local system accounts, a virtual mailbox domain  [address class]. It has a default transport, virtual, you can change it of course, but it is advisable to change it to something conceptually similar, e.g. for Cyrus IMAP, you would change it to lmtp to forward mails to Cyrus's LMTP server. It is not very well suitable for mail to be relayed to different mail system.
The virtual_alias_domains doesn't have any default transport at all and its purpose is to implement analogue of alias_maps for virtual (non-local) addresses, because alias_maps itself only works for local address class. It should be thought as a complementary for the virtual mailbox domains, so you can declare some addresses in virtual_mailbox_domains that are not mailboxes. It is not suitable for relaying either.
There is an address class that is specially dedicated for relay work — relay address class. And it uses a transport_maps first, then relay if domain is not found in transport maps, which is alias of SMTP, so it already uses the transport you need, no need to redefine. This is the built-in logic that you were trying to re-implement, and this would be the right way.
The list of domains to relay (to map into this address class) is specified as relay_domains, and the list of known addresses (to filter out undeliverable mail early) is specified relay_address_maps; it would be that large table you fill and sync automatically from your client's mail system. If you're not convinced this is a good thing, you may use regexe or catch-all entries in relay address maps.
